# Video upload script PHP

Tags: php, html

I am creating a social site that gives users the option to upload images and videos.
When I try to upload images they get uploaded, but when I try to upload videos only the post text gets uploaded but the video doesn't. It doesn't go in the DB or uploads folder.

I am using the exact same code for my videos as I did my images but I can't find the bug. Can someone please help me ?

create_subtopic.php :

```
<form action="imgupload/index3.php?topic_tosend=<?php echo urlencode($topic_toget); ?>"
            method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<div class="insert_image">

    <input type='file' multiple="multiple" onchange='openFile(event)' class='uploader' 
                        id="imageToUpload" name="files[]" accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="image_icon" width="25" height="25" 
                        fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-image-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            
        <path d="M.002 3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h12a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v10a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-12a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V3zm1 9v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V9.5l-3.777-1.947a.5.5 0 0 0-.577.093l-3.71 3.71-2.66-1.772a.5.5 0 0 0-.63.062L1.002 12zm5-6.5a1.5 1.5 0 1 0-3 0 1.5 1.5 0 0 0 3 0z" />

    </svg>

</div>

<div class="insert_video">

    <input type='file' multiple="" onchange='openFile(event)' 
                        class='video_uploader' id="videoToUpload" name="files[]" 
                        accept="video/mp4,video/quicktime" />

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="video_icon" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-camera-video-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h7.5a2 2 0 0 1 1.983 1.738l3.11-1.382A1 1 0 0 1 16 4.269v7.462a1 1 0 0 1-1.406.913l-3.111-1.382A2 2 0 0 1 9.5 13H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V5z" />
    </svg>

    </div>

</form>
```

---

index3.php:

```
$date_time = date('Y-m-d_H-i-s');
$img_limit = 10;
$maxsize = 9367463;

//if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST)) {

    //var_dump($_POST['viewkey']);
    $topic_tosend = $_GET['topic_tosend'] ?? '';
//}

$_SESSION['title_post'] = $_POST['title_post'];
$_SESSION['description'] = $_POST['description'];

if(isset($_POST['create_sub_topic'])) {

    $errors = '';

    if ($topic_tosend == '') {
        
        $errors = "Choose a topic.";

    } else {

        if ($errors == 0) {            

            $create_topic = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO subtopic (sub_topic, description, 
                topic, created_by) 
             VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $create_topic->bind_param("ssss", $_POST['title_post'], $_POST['description'], 
                $topic_tosend, $userLoggedIn);
            $create_topic->execute();
        }
    }

    // --------------- CHECK IMAGES ----------****

    if(!file_exists($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0]) || !is_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0])){

        if (!$errors) {
            
            header('Location: ../index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }
    
    $file_count = count($_FILES['files']['name']);

    if ($file_count > $img_limit) {

        $errors = 'Cannot upload more than 10 images';
    }

    if (!$errors) {

        $id = mysqli_insert_id($con);

        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO subtopic_images (sub_topic, subtopic_id, 
            image, added_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('siss', $_POST['title_post'], $id, $file_path, $userLoggedIn);

        // Loop through each file
        for( $i=0; $i < $file_count; $i++ ) {

            $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
            $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
            $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
        
            $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

            if ($file_size >= $maxsize) {

                $errors = "Your file is too large";

            } elseif ($imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "mp4" && 
                $imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {

                $errors = "File type not allowed.";
            }
            //Make sure we have a file path
            if (!$errors /* && $file_tmp != "" */) {

                $picToUpload =  md5($file_name). $date_time . $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                $uploadPicture = move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "../uploads/" . $picToUpload);

                $file_path = "uploads/" . $picToUpload;
                $stmt->execute();
            }
        }
    }
    // --------------- CHECK IMAGES ----------****
}

if ($errors) {

    $_SESSION['error'] = '<b><p style="color: #000; font-size: 30px; top: 34%;right: 50%;
    position: absolute;"> ' . $errors . '</p></b>';
}

header('Location: ../create_subtopic.php');
exit();
```

Comment: try to use different name for `input type='file'`?

Comment: @MichaelLaw I combined the two of them and it worked. Would that be a problem down the line ?

Comment: well...I am not sure. Just list out something I think it may cause the program~

Answer (score 0):

Check if it works if you remove the "accept" attribute

EDIT: Michael Law is right, you have 2 inputs with the same name in one form